# Optimized solution for replacing repeating column values with NULL

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following structure and data:

| Time | Company | AttriA | AttriB | AttriC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/4/2020 13:21 | TestA | 12 | 1 | 2 |
| 12/4/2020 13:21 | TestB | 1 | 2 | 44 |
| 12/4/2020 13:22 | TestB | 34 | 3 | 44 |
| 12/4/2020 13:22 | TestA | 12 | 4 | 5 |
| 12/4/2020 13:21 | TestC | 15 | 5 | 4 |

What I want to achieve is the following:

- If, for a particular company, there are **consecutive, repeating values in time** in the AttriX (X = A, B or C) columns, then I want to replace those repeating values with NULLs.
- The data is huge, in the order of a few million and the query has to be performant as well.

Going by the above logic, the view I am trying to create should return me data like this:

| Time | Company | AttriA | AttriB | AttriC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/4/2020 13:21 | TestA | NULL | 1 | 2 |
| 12/4/2020 13:21 | TestB | 1 | 2 | NULL |
| 12/4/2020 13:22 | TestB | 34 | 3 | NULL |
| 12/4/2020 13:22 | TestA | NULL | 4 | 5 |
| 12/4/2020 13:21 | TestC | 15 | 5 | 4 |

I've hit a wall with this. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Apologies if you have to run the snippet to see the table. I was trying to make it neat.

Comment: Stackoverflow has a table option btw and ascii table works best for most.

Comment: You tagged "sql", but only show some html rendering of something. What database? What database structure? How do you query your database and how do generate your html from the results of that query?

Comment: @mivk  - I ve updated the post to reflect the table.

Comment: @venky yes I saw that and updated the post. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you means same rows result, that doesn't need to manipulate from query. cause you can paging the query result, and then make some validation on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lead(attria) over (partition by company order by time) = attria or
                  lag(attria) over (partition by company order by time) = attria
             then null
             else attria
        end),
       (case when lead(attrib) over (partition by company order by time) = attrib or
                  lag(attrib) over (partition by company order by time) = attrib
             then null
             else attrib
        end),
       (case when lead(attric) over (partition by company order by time) = attric or
                  lag(attric) over (partition by company order by time) = attric
             then null
             else attric
        end)
from t
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Gordon Linoff. This definitely works. Is there a way in which I can leave the first value as it is and from the second repeating value replace with NULLs?

Comment: @thestarsailor . . . I don't understand your comment.  Doesn't this return the data you want?

Comment: @thestarsailor . . . This should work on the data you have presented in your question.  There are multiple reasons why it might not work on your data.  Perhaps the column values *look* the same but are not (say due to trailing spaces or hidden characters).  Perhaps you have exact ties on time values.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with an example of where it is not working.

Comment: what i meant was like, can we somehow say something like, if there is more than 1 repeating value before the current value or more than 1 repeating value after, then make it null.

Comment: @thestarsailor . . . This answer handles that situation.